How to make full-buffer traffic in NS-3 LTE-module
I've already read documentation for LTE-module and EPC packets, but I don't understand how can I create full-buffer traffic. Info about probably here:
https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/lte-user.html (19.2), I tried but its still not working(.
How I have this code:
#include <ns3/core-module.h>
#include <ns3/network-module.h>
#include <ns3/mobility-module.h>
#include <ns3/lte-module.h>
#include <ns3/internet-module.h>
#include <ns3/point-to-point-module.h>
#include <ns3/applications-module.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace ns3;

//defines for simple code

#define pfff "ns3::PfFfMacScheduler"
#define const_pos_model "ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel"
#define simTime Seconds(10);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //creating UE and ENB (2 and 1)
  Ptr<LteHelper> lteHelper = CreateObject<LteHelper>();
  NodeContainer enbNodes;
  enbNodes.Create(1);
  NodeContainer ueNodes;
  ueNodes.Create(2);

  //creating class instance for using mobility 

  MobilityHelper mobility;

  //setup the position of ue 

  Ptr<ListPositionAllocator> UEposition = CreateObject<ListPositionAllocator> ();
  UEposition->Add(Vector (1.0,1.0, 0.0));
  UEposition->Add(Vector (1.0,-1.0, 0.0));
  mobility.SetPositionAllocator(UEposition);
  mobility.SetMobilityModel(const_pos_model);
  mobility.Install(ueNodes);

  //setup the position of enb
  Ptr<ListPositionAllocator> ENBposition = CreateObject<ListPositionAllocator> ();
  ENBposition->Add(Vector (0.0,0.0,0.0));
  mobility.SetPositionAllocator(ENBposition);
  mobility.SetMobilityModel(const_pos_model);
  mobility.Install(enbNodes);

  //setup pfff scheduler

  lteHelper->SetSchedulerType(pfff);

  //install LTE settings on UE and ENB devices

  NetDeviceContainer enbDevs;
  enbDevs = lteHelper->InstallEnbDevice(enbNodes);
  NetDeviceContainer ueDevs;
  ueDevs = lteHelper->InstallUeDevice(ueNodes);


  lteHelper->Attach(ueDevs, enbDevs.Get(0));
  enum EpsBearer::Qci q = EpsBearer::GBR_CONV_VOICE;
  EpsBearer bearer(q);
  lteHelper->ActivateDataRadioBearer(ueDevs, bearer);

 
  lteHelper->EnableMacTraces();
  lteHelper->EnableRlcTraces();
  
  Simulator::Stop(Seconds(10));

  Simulator::Run();

  Simulator::Destroy();


  return 0;
}

Its minimal LTE-simulation. And I need to add here full-buffer traffic. I'm a beginner in this but now I have no ideas. Thanks a lot for helping one more time.
P.S. - It's a program which simulates 2 UE and 1 ENB with full-traffic, other settings I installed.

you can use                                                                Time interPacketInterval = MilliSeconds(1);  //1ms for  full buffer and 10ms for non - buffer  scenario
